# Is iPhone (iOS) able to use categories for contacts (and to recognize Outlook categories)?

Tags: ios, iphone, outlook, contacts

I have my Outlook contacts tagged with categories. I found no way of syncing this info to iPhone (iOS 6).

But more fundamentally, I found no place where iOS stores such info for contacts. Of course, if this info is not stored, there is no way to sync it.
**Can anyone clarify this point?**

I posted an answer with a poor workaround.
I did not write the script, since perhaps there are better options.
**Is there any other alternative to this?**

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use groups to mimic the categories in Outlook.

Comment: I think the concepts are different. This is exactly the workaround that I proposed, with a few downsides: 1) In Outlook, one has to create one group for each category, and take each contact and copy it into several categories - after syncing Outlook->iOS one has to clean up; 2) The number of contacts may increase a lot, depending on the average number of categories each contact belongs to; 3) Copies of a contact become independent of each other, so it may be messy to modify one of them; 4) I do not know how to deal neatly with sync iOS->Outlook. Could you clarify if you meant something else?

Comment: I think that categories are like Gmail labels, groups are like Windows folders (with no possibility of having shortcuts).

Comment: I dare say that you are right, and I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround (poor in my view, though useful if having something alternative to categories becomes mandatory).
iOS has contact groups, which sync with Outlook contact groups. Thus, one could write a VBA script that takes each Category, and creates a corresponding contact group. Then, each contact would be copied to all the groups corresponding to its categories. After syncing, a cleanup in Outlook would be performed to restore the original state. If all contacts are in a single group, cleanup would possibly be easier.

The downsides of this approach are:

1. Programming work.
2. The total number of contacts will be increased (perhaps a lot) if contacts are included in more than one category; each contact will be multiplied by the number of categories it belongs to.
3. Copies of a contact become independent of each other, so it may be messy to modify one of them in iOS.
4. Dealing neatly with sync iOS->Outlook may be tricky.